# Vulkan rendering to texture makes movement jittery

Tags: c++, vulkan, imgui

When rendering to the main window viewport using Vulkan, movement is smooth as expected. But when rendering to a separate framebuffer movement becomes jittery.

Rendering straight to the window:

[image: rendering to a window]

Rendering to a framebuffer (and rendering it with ImGui):

[image: rendering to a framebuffer]

Creating a framebuffer creates a new render pass, a new command pool and command buffers, a new depth and color attachment images, new framebuffers, a texture sampler and adds the images to ImGui using `ImGui_ImplVulkan_AddTexture`.

Comment: when you move the imgui windows around, are they jittery as well?

Comment: @Avi it only happens when rendering to the texture